# Web Scraping with BeautifulSoup - how to set delay for Scraping when accessing site?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the entries from Immobilienscout24, which is a german real estate listing platform.

Whenever i want to scrape a site, it only scrapes "Ich bin kein Roboter" (in german "i am not a robot") as header. I found out that sometimes, when you enter the site, for half a second you get a screen that says something like "youll be redirected soon" and additional infos that state that they want to make sure youre not a robot by redirecting to the requested site (only sometimes though, which is why i dont understand that the result of my scraping is always the robot-paragraph).

This leads me to my question: is there a way to bypass that short redirection or handle the url in a way that doesent just read the initial "redirection-site"?

Comment: its a captcha.. captcha exists for the purpose of preventing bots.. so your question is kinda paradoxical asking to bypass a botcheck using your bot??

Answer (score 0):

This solution might not work for your problem, but solved for me.
Before using this you should download the appropriate driver for your browser, and uncomment only one time the lines bellow

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

if os.environ['PATH'].find(';C:\\SeleniumDrivers') > 0:
    pass
else:
  os.environ['PATH'] += ";C:\\SeleniumDrivers"  

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # or another adequate time
driver.get('https://www.yoursitegoeshere.com')

    with open("your_output_source_file.html", "w", encoding='utf8') as f:
        f.write(driver.page_source)
```

Then you can use beautiful soup on the raw html file and do the manipulations you want.